# Trouble retrieving form values from VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dotnetnuke

I've created a module for my website and when a button is clicked, it calls a VB sub on the server.

I need this sub to retrieve the values that were filled in on the form, but the things I need to retrieve values from are not asp controls, they are simple `<input>` and `<select>` tags.

How can I retrieve values from input on a .aspx page from VB code executed behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go : http://www.geekpedia.com/KB16_How-do-I-get-the-values-when-submitting-a-form-(either-using-GET-or-POST).html

In you sub, you must use the *request* object. 
More infos here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231199(VS.60).aspx

Hope this help you ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your HTML

```
<input id="firstName" name="firstName />
```

Your VB.NET

```
Dim firstName as String = Request.Form("firstName")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Request.Form object` for POST.
Or the `Request.QueryString` for GET.